# Windows 10 UAC/System Installer

Tags: administrator, windows-installer

I am running Windows 10 Pro [Build 10240] and upon logging in tonight I find I am unable to install an MSI file as `The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation` only, I do not recall doing this, at all.

So I did a little digging and found [this pos](https://serverfault.com/questions/580972/why-is-this-preventing-me-installing-an-msi-the-system-administrator-has-set-po)t, pretty cool. The best solution on this post was to run the install from an elevated command prompt, so I ran the following command:

```
msiexec /i example.msi
```

This resulted in the same outcome. Using the `/a` switch also did not help me. So I did more digging and found a "fantastic" Microsoft post [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/the-system-administrator-has-set-policies-to/71d2a00c-0e87-4fe1-abae-4b44b4dbeef4?auth=1). It applies to Windows 7, so I guess that's why the key does not exist on Windows 10 - the solution was to set `DisableMSI` with `REG_DWORD = 0` in the `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Installer`directory.

So, square 1. Another solution is to set UAC to never notify...isn't this default on a home system? Ran though and double checked it was set to never notify, rebooted, no change.

I wept for hours until I found another option. The next solution I found was to edit the Local Security Policy for `Software Restriction Policies`. I messed around in here and could not isolate where to add the entry. I added a new hash for `%userprofile%\Downloads\` to allow all users to execute file types and ensure MSI was in the list.

I have ensured that my Anti-Virus is not blocking the registry changes, disabled all shields and re-attempted to no luck. I am now performing a full system scan to see if there are any threats on my PC. Long shot, but worth it.

Whilst that is running, I have made a new local account on the PC and ensured it admin rights. I've ran `mmc` and ensured it in the `Local User and Group` `Administrators` group. Once the scan is done I plan on logging out, and attempting to install. I doubt this a user restricted issue but want to rule it out as an issue.

Next I ran `gpresult /h report.html` and have a quick look to see if I had messed up GPO (I do set local GPO) and all looked well; just my standard disable of gadgets/Cortana etc.

Next I ran `sfc.exe /scannow` and found no issues here. Frustrated, I went and edited the following values in Local Group Policy:

`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Installer` with the following:

`Install with Elevated privileges` set to enable.

`Turn off Windows Installer` set to disabled.

Same option with User Configuration. The last step is I have redownloaded the MSI and validated it not corrupt (works on Win8 VM). Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: “set UAC to never notify...isn't this default on a home system?” No, that would undermine the entire idea. // Don’t forget to accept your answer when you can. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rolled back to a previous image, and performed a `sfc` and found multiple errors. I repaired the install, updated (via Windows Update) and now am able to perform the above mentioned.